# Pigeonhole principle, $20$ translators and $18$ languages.

Tags: combinatorics, arithmetic, pigeonhole-principle

I stuck with the following problem, which I think is relevant with pigeonhole principle.

> **Problem**. There are $20$ translators and $18$ languages. It is known
>   that for every given language there are  exactly $5$ translators who know it. Is it true,
>   that we can always choose $5$ translators, such that for every
>   language there exists at least one  translator knowing this language.

My attempt. We can connect every language with translators knowing it. There are $90$ arrows in our "graph". Of course there exists a translator knowing at least $5$ languages (by pigeonhole principle). After that we can remove from our graph $1$ translator and at least $5$ languages known to him. We can continue using this greedy strategy, but it is easyly to see, that it will not lead to success.

So, I will be gratefull for ideas and hints.

Comment: What does this mean: "It is known that every language is known by exactly 5 translators." Does this mean that there are 5 translators whom, _together_, know every language and no more, or that there are exactly 5 translators each of whom _individually_ know all 18 languages?

Comment: This means the following.    Assume that there the languges are $l_1, \ldots l_{18}$ and translators are $t_1, t_2, \ldots, t_{20}$. Without loss of generality we can assume that $t_1, t_2, t_3, t_4, t_5$ know $l_1$ and $t_6, \ldots, t_{20}$ don't know $l_1$.

Comment: Ah, so "for any given language, there are exactly 5 translators who know it".

Comment: Yes, you are right. I will specify a formulation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assume that for $1\le i\le 6$, language $L_i$ is known by translator $T_j$ iff $1\le j\le6$ and $i\ne j$.
And for $7\le i\le 12$, language $L_i$ is known by translator $T_j$ iff $7\le j\le12$ and $i\ne j$.
And for $13\le i\le 18$, language $L_i$ is known by translator $T_j$ iff $13\le j\le18$ and $i\ne j$.
Then each $L_i$ is known by exactly five $L_j$ (and $T_{19}$ and $T_{20}$ are not worth their money). However, in order to cover all $18$ languages, we need two translators from $T_1,\ldots,T_6$, two translators from $T_7,\ldots,T_{12}$, and two translators from $T_{13},\ldots,T_{18}$.

Comment: Thank you, very much for the demonstrative solution!